# How can I implement onClickListner in this ViewPager2 image slider in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I want to implement OnClickListener in this ViewPager2 Image Slide. I want to click different images to take me to different activities. Like clicking the first slider image will open the second activity, the second image will open the third activity and so on. This is the Java code I am using for the Event image slider.

```
List<SliderItem> sliderItems = new ArrayList<>();
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.sliderimg1));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.sliderimg2));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.sliderimg3));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.sliderimg4));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.sliderimg5));

    viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItems,viewPager2));
    viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
    viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    CompositePageTransformer compositePageTransformer = new CompositePageTransformer();
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(40));
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
            float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
            page.setScaleY(0.85f + r*0.15f);
           
        }
    });

    viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
    viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            sliderHandler.removeCallbacks(sliderRunnable);
            sliderHandler.postDelayed(sliderRunnable,3000);
        }
    });
```

**Can anyone help me to implement the onclicklistner?**

Comment: viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback is working properly?

Comment: Have you tried this: 
 viewPager2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
        });

Comment: Implement Onclick inside SliderAdapter class